# Is there a list of all the MySQL errors that can happen on an INSERT query?

Tags: mysql

The error code list for MySQL is documented here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-error-reference.html

But the errors are not classified and I need specifically the errors that can happen on an INSERT query.

I've found some:

1062 => insert duplicated value for unique key

1054 => unknown column

1051 => unknown table

1065 => incorrect query syntax

Comment: Can you tell us why? You could get disk full,  wrong data types, duplicates, NOT NULL warnings,  ...  goodness, my head aches already

Comment: I just need to report these errors to the end user on an app, overriding the mysql messages with more user friendly messages, by checking error codes. Besides the reason, the requirement is exactly as stated on the question, so if there are many error codes, all those should be checked. The issue is, as stated, the MySQL doc mixes many error types together, for instance connection errors and query related errors. On the other hand, I'm more concerned for app level errors like duplicates and wrong data, than infrastructure errors like disk full.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya read the question, already has a link to that list, I need a specific subset as stated on the question.

Comment: Nice objective, but for debugging you will likely want access to the dbms message, and no matter how exhaustive you are with the subset, you will probably also need `"Unexpected error: " & dbms-message` anyway. Good luck.

Comment: Three of the errors you mentioned as examples should *never* be exposed to users of your app... because they should never occur.  If they do occur, then you have design defects, bugs, and/or security vulnerabilities.  It should not be possible for a user action or user input to cause an unknown table/column or empty query/syntax error, or several others.  If they can, and do, then when you reveal the error to the user, you are also providing malicious actors with information they may find useful in exploiting your vulnerabilities.  Reconsider your strategy.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot as said on other comment, errors will be rewritten for users. Also, I would say your recommendation depends on the type of user and type of application. For instance, an application to manage a database would certainly expose those errors to users. Either way this is not the case. I just need to error codes as mentioned in the question. Thanks.

Comment: @Used_By_Already thanks, but this is not for debugging.